# Features extraction from tweets

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, language-features

I am using Python language and i got tweets from twitter. Now the next thing i want to do is to extract features from that tweets features like:
1. Features A (statistical features): the number of words in a tweet message, and the position of the query word within a tweet.
2. Features B (keyword features): the words in a tweet.
3. Features C (word context features): the words before and after the query word.
for example:
Feature A: 7 words in tweet, query word is fifth
Feature B: I,am,in,Japan,right,now
Feature C: Japan,right

suggest me some good method to extract those features. As i am not getting a right way to extract features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the following libraries:

1. [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)
2. [SKLearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

Depending on what you need to get done, a mix between these two can get you a long way.

Also for an introduction into Natural Language Processing, I would recommend [this book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) (free to read online).